# AnyLogic Error Handling: How to say if there's an error, move to the next block

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I have a rail yard simulation in AnyLogic, and I create different car types based on a schedule. Then, I use TrainCouple to create one train with a dynamic, specific number of each car. However, if the number for a certain car type is 0, I run into a problem because the train is trying to couple with nothing. I was thinking I could resolve this problem by doing an error handler where every time there's an error, it would force move to the next flowchart block. Does anyone know how to do this, or have any other ideas for how to deal with this problem?

Comment: can't you use a simple selectoutput to avoid sending it to couple if the value is 0?

Comment: I think I need a way to force move to the next block because I use trainSource blocks, which also don't work when trying to create a 0 car train

Comment: you need to add more info... flows and rails to get help..